# How to iframe in angular4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, iframe

I got this in my angular2 v4 app:

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></iframe>
```

but it doesn't work. How can I make this work? I tried using `| safe` but it does not work either. Please help

Comment: Please do not attempt to learn from https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: @AluanHaddad why?

Comment: @Steve because it provides incorrect information and promotes exceptionally bad practices to this day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to look in your console, you'd probably see this message:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

The `X-Frame-Options` header allows websites to prevent sites with differing origins (domains) from using them within an `<iframe/>`. This basically means that only pages hosted on `www.w3schools.com` can use that url in an `<iframe/>` source. [You can read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

You code (which you neglected so share much of) is most likely okay syntactically. You can try another url for your `<iframe/>`.